# integer and decimal are used to describe fields in return types but not in method parameters

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, api-v2, documentation

Integer and Decimal designations are useful in creating an accurate model of API methods and types.

These specific 'number' subtypes are used when describing types but the method parameter lists all use the more generic 'number' type.

It would be helpful if the method parameters which are numeric were more specifically typed.

Comment: Hey - great to see you! I haven't seen you in a while!

Comment: @geo - been busy the last couple years making money writing json api stacks. i won't be nearly as noisy as last time but there is a v2 release in the works based on the work i have done these past couple years.

Comment: Cool. Well, it's great to have you back here for the v2.0 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All numbers sent to the API as parameters are whole integers, this is made explicit in the [Numbers documentation page](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/numbers) now.

It has always been explicit in terms of parameter validation in the console, but it's now spelled out (along with bit sizes, which were not available before).